# Как менять размер GameObject в зависимости от размера камеры Unity2d

Tags: c#, unity3d, .net

У меня в Камере, Size меняется (режим Orthographic), но мне надо - что бы при этом все объекты на фоне тоже увеличивались пропорционально

Comment: И зачем тогда менять Size?

Comment: У камеры меняется Size раз в 10 сек, и при этом все обьекты на фоне уменьшаются, как я могу это изменить?

Comment: Уточните что конкретно меняется: угол обзора, дистанция камеры от объектов или нечто ещё?

Comment: @AlexandrKosolobov Дистанция вряд ли, ведь камера Orthographic.  так понимаю, имеется в виду сам параметр [Size](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Camera-orthographicSize.html), но я решительным образом не понимаю, для чего это нужно.

Comment: Вы можете создать событие event на изменение Size, и подписаться на это событие со всех нужных объектов функцией изменения размера. Создать для этого какой-то класс CameraSizeFitter, что ли. Но по-моему у вас ошибка уже на уровне изменения размера камеры. Зачем это может понадобиться?

Comment: Мой персонаж увеличивается раз в 10сек, и что бы он помещался в камеру, я меняю Size в камере, но при этом, остальные объекты на сцене со временем перестают быть видимыми, и вот я не знаю по какой формуле(или еще чем-то) менять их размер на тот, что и был, просто с новым размером камеры

Answer (score 0):

Как предложил Максим Фисман вашу проблему можно решить следующим образом:

1. Создать событие увеличения размера персонажа
2. Сделать скрипт Scalable для объектов, изменяющих размер. Они должны реализовать функцию увеличения размера Scale с параметром как у персонажа
3. Подписать этот метод на событие увеличения размера

Какие проблемы вы можете встретить:

1. Объекты не будут отдаляться друг от друга при увеличении размера. Это может привести к наслаиванию объектов друг на друга

Решение:

1. Объединить все объекты окружения "изменяющих свой размер" в один префаб или пустой объект и повесить скрипт Scalable в на "родитель"

Правка1: в моем представлении код должен выглядить примерно следующим образом:

```
public class Scalable : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] private ScaleEventManager ScaleEventKeeper;

    private void OnScaleEvent(float scale)
    {
        transform.localScale = new Vector3(scale, scale, scale);
    }

    private void EnebleScaling()
    {
        ScaleEventKeeper.ScaleEvent += OnScaleEvent;
    }

    private void DisableScaling()
    {
        ScaleEventKeeper.ScaleEvent -= OnScaleEvent;
    }
}

public class ScaleEventManager : MonoBehaviour
{
    public delegate void ScaleDelegate(float scale);
    public event ScaleDelegate ScaleEvent;
    private const float WAIT_FOR_SECONDS = 10f;
    private const float STARTING_SCALE = 1f;
    private const float SCALE_MODIFIER = 1.1f;
    private float _currentScale;

    private void Awake()
    {
        StartCoroutine(RescaleEverySeconds());
    }

    private IEnumerator RescaleEverySeconds()
    {
        _currentScale = STARTING_SCALE * SCALE_MODIFIER;
        while (true)
        {
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(WAIT_FOR_SECONDS);
            ScaleEvent(_currentScale);
            _currentScale *= SCALE_MODIFIER;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Так же это лишит вас возможности сделать "окружение" статичным. Так делают для того, чтобы юнити объединял все статики в один объект. Это должно уменьшать нагрузку на CPU

Comment: Кстати говоря, хоть я и написал логику изменения размера в MyHero вам я рекомендую вынести эту логику в отдельный ScaleEventManager, который только вызывает ScaleEvent(scale) каждые 10 секунд, а сам персонаж также будет содержать в себе Scalable. Более того, если у вас нет привязки к конкретному параметру scale, вы можете изменить формулу, чтобы лишь увеличивать\уменьшать размеры объектов на определенный процент.

Comment: В общем я исправил всё, о чём говорил во втором комментарии